# Grab similar data and do the math operation on the grabbed data

Tags: shell, grep

I need to search the value of each student attendance from below table and need to do summation of each student attendance.

I have a file dump with below data inside file_dump.txt

```
 [days   Leaves PERCENTAGE  student_attendance]
   194     1.3  31.44%      student1.entry2
   189     1.3  30.63%      student2._student2
   138     0.9  22.37%      student3.entry2
     5     0.0   0.81%      student3._student3
     5     0.0   0.81%      student1._student1
```

I need to search student1 data from above table using linux command (grep or other commands) and then do the summation of student1.entry2 and  student1._student1 together that is ( 194 + 5 = 199).

How can I do this using linux command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is eminently suitable for small programming tasks like this.

```sh
awk -v student="student1" '$4 ~ "^" student "\." { sum += $1 }
    END { print sum }' file
```

The `-v` option lets you pass in a value for an Awk variable  from the command line; we do that to provide a value for the variable `student`. The first line checks whether the fourth field `$4` begins with that variable immediately followed by a dot, and if so, adds the first field `$1` to the variable `sum`. (Conveniently, uninitialized variables spring to life with a default value of zero / empty string.) This gets repeated for each input line in the file. Then the `END` block gets executed after the input file has been exhausted, and we print the accumulated sum.

If you want to save this in an executable script, you might want to allow the caller to specify the student to search for:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Fail if $1 is unset
: ${1?Syntax: $0 studentname}
awk -v student="$1" '$4 ~ "^" student "\." { sum += $1 }
    END { print sum }' file
```

Notice how the `$` variables inside the single quotes are Awk field names (the single quotes protect the script's contents from the shell's variable interpolation etc facilities), whereas the one with double quotes around it gets replaced by the shell with the value of the first command-line argument.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for your answer. Can you please tell me how I can write the same in make file. I need final output in result.txt file with all students attendance information .I need to add this logic in make file.

Comment: `cut -c 1- file_dump.txt | awk -v student="student1" '$4 ~ "^" student "\." { sum += $1 } END { print sum }' file_dump.txt `

Comment: You don't need the `cut` there, Awk can do that handsomely too (but `cut -c1-` doesn't actually perform any useful function). You don't pass a file name argument to Awk when you want it to read from a pipe. The main thing in a Makefile is to double the dollar signs.